# How to access my Home Ubuntu server from Office

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, router, static-ip

I have a Beetel 450TC2 router with 192.168.1.1 ... I have configured Static IP in it ... Now I have two computers... One with windows 8 and the other with ubuntu server 12.04 ... The IP in the windows machine is 192.168.1.2 and for the Ubuntu server is 192.168.1.3 ... I have changed the ssh port for ubuntu server as 55210... Now I dont know how to access my ubuntu server from office computer ... Please help on this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup port forwarding in your router. Then you ssh to the routers public ip with the forwarding port from your office. Voila!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply ... But can you help me on how to do port forwarding in my Modem cum router ... Thanks in advance ...

Comment: While not being the exact same model, [this guide](http://www.goelsanjay.com/2007/06/port-forwarding-in-airtel-modem.html?m=1) should get you started